# Combine Dictionary with different levels in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary in C# that has a structure like this:

```
{
  "PriceApproval": 0,
  "ListOffers": [
    {
      "EAN": "7701410118349",
      "Stock": "3",
      "Price": "16000.00",
      "DiscountPrice": "20000.00",
      "AverageFreightCost": "25000.00",
      "PromiseDelivery": "1 a 10",
      "Warranty": 50,
      "IsFreeShipping": 0,
      "IsEnviosExito": 0,
      "IsFreightCalculator": 0,
      "IsLogisticsExito": 0,
      "IsUpdatedStock": 1,
      "Currency": "COP",
      "Periodicity": 1
     }
   ]
}
```

What dictionary structure should I use?
I want to send it as content in a `httpRequestMessage`, using JSON like this:

`Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info))`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal in doing this? What are you planning to do with that Dictionary? There might be better ways to do it.

Comment: I want to add it as content to a httpRequestMessage

Comment: What kind of format do you have to send it as? Ideally, sending it as JSON is best (then you don't need a Dictionary). But are you saying that you have to send it as form data?

Comment: I am actually sending it with JSON using the code StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info))

Comment: Then why do you need a Dictionary?

Comment: thanks for your responces Gabriel. No i don't need a Dictionary, actually any way of doing it works for me, do you have any ideas?

Comment: So do you have this data as a JSON string right now? And you want to take that string, turn it into a C# object, and then send it in an HTTP request? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: No, the example shown above is how the service expects the content to be sent. i tried creating it as Dictionary and then converting it to JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one value is an `int` (or really any numeric type) and the other is another dictionary whose values are a mix of numbers ans strings, the best you can hope for out-of-the-box is `Dictionary<string, object>`. If you want a more strongly-typed solution you could define a class hierarchy (using more meaningful names, of course):

```
public class Info
{
    public int PriceApproval {get; set;}
    public ListOffer[] ListOffers {get; set;}
}
public class ListOffer
{
    public string EAN {get; set;}
    public int Warranty {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Comment: The class is the way to go.